# can't download 20 newsgroups data via python code

Tags: scikit-learn

I am trying to run the classification demo base on 20news group, I download the py file here (http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/text/document_classification_20newsgroups.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-text-document-classification-20newsgroups-py) and run the python code as usual but got below error which says there is a network connection timeout error, I am a little confused since I can download the data file from the provided URL(https://ndownloader.figshare.com/files/5975967), does anyone know how to resolve this issue? Is there anyway I can use the manuelly downloaded data file?

Environment:
Python 3.6
Ananconda 5.0.1

Comment: Error Detail :                                                                            
 TimeoutError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py in do_open(self, http_class, req, **http_conn_args)
   1317                 h.request(req.get_method(), req.selector, req.data, headers,
-> 1318                           encode_chunked=req.has_header('Transfer-encoding'))
   1319             except OSError as err: # timeout error

Comment: Maybe you are using a proxy and / or anaconda is not allowed to access them.

Answer (score 4):

Quoting from [scikit-learn docs](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/datasets/twenty_newsgroups.html#newsgroups):

> The `sklearn.datasets.fetch_20newsgroups` function is a data fetching / caching functions that downloads the data archive from the original 20 newsgroups website, extracts the archive contents in the **~/scikit_learn_data/20news_home** folder and calls the `sklearn.datasets.load_files` on either the training or testing set folder, or both of them.

You can use the manually downloaded file simply by extracting it to the specified folder.

Alternatively, you can specify the data folder when calling `fetch_20newsgroups` function by passing `data_home='/path/to/data'`. Change the function call to be like this:

```
data_train = fetch_20newsgroups(data_home='/path/to/data',
                                subset='train', categories=categories,
                                shuffle=True, random_state=42,
                                remove=remove)

data_test = fetch_20newsgroups(data_home='/path/to/data',
                               subset='test', categories=categories,
                               shuffle=True, random_state=42,
                               remove=remove)
```